# How can I diagnose a mono service terminating unexpectedly?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, mono

I've written a .net 4.0 mono service and am hosting it on a Raspberry Pi.

It runs on system startup via a .sh file which has the following code:

```
cd /var/supernovaServer
mono-service -l:/var/supernovaServer/snserver.lock /var/supernovaServer/snserver.exe
```

After some time, sometimes hours, and sometimes days, the process terminates and leaves the snserver.lock file in place. Custom logging code that I have written via a StreamWriter seems to have not flushed the last few messages and my custom log file seems incomplete when I examine it.

What steps can I take to diagnose this issue and prevent the service from terminating? i.e. Are there any log files for mono I could look at? I'm still somewhat new to Linux so I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You may run strace against the PID of your application and log `strace` output (be prepared to take a good amount of disk, if it is to take hours or days).

Other strategy could be use GDB debugger, or launch `mono` with `--debug` option:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/